# C# How to get the AD user cannot change the password property from LDAP attribute userAccountControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory, user-account-control

I am trying to get the user account control properties using library `Novell.Directory.Ldap` in `ASP .NET Core 5`. When I search the users attributes I found the attribute name `userAccountControl` which is set to some number. After searching solution I am able to find:

```
bool isUserActive = false;
bool userMustChangePassword = false;
bool passwordNeverExpires = false;
bool passwordCannotBeChanged = false;

var flags = Convert.ToInt32(attributeSet.GetAttribute("userAccountControl").StringValue);
isUserActive = !Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0002); //1. checks if user is enabled
if ((flags == 66048)) //65536+512
{
  passwordNeverExpires = true; //2. Password never expires property
}
long value = Convert.ToInt64(attributeSet.GetAttribute("pwdLastSet").StringValue);
if (value == 0)
{
    userMustChangePassword = true; //3. User must change password at next login
}
```

But I am not able to figure out how to get the `User cannot change password` and if the `account is locked` properties? Or how can I compare the binary value like `0x0040`? Please help

Edit:

I tried the steps given by @Gabriel Luci in https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2019/07/25/nt-security-descriptors.html and tried following code:

```
var act = attributeSet.GetAttribute("nTSecurityDescriptor").ByteValue;
ADsSecurityUtility secUtility = new ADsSecurityUtility();
IADsSecurityDescriptor convertAttrToSD = (IADsSecurityDescriptor)secUtility.ConvertSecurityDescriptor(act, (int)ADS_SD_FORMAT_ENUM.ADS_SD_FORMAT_RAW, (int)ADS_SD_FORMAT_ENUM.ADS_SD_FORMAT_IID);
var byteArray = (byte[])secUtility.ConvertSecurityDescriptor(
                            convertAttrToSD,
                            (int)ADS_SD_FORMAT_ENUM.ADS_SD_FORMAT_IID,
                            (int)ADS_SD_FORMAT_ENUM.ADS_SD_FORMAT_RAW
                         );
var security = new CommonSecurityDescriptor(true, true, byteArray, 0);
```

If I check the `security` it shows [image]

I am not getting where to look user cannot change the password settings?

Edit 2:
According to @Gabriel Luci updated answer, it worked for me like this:

```
var constraints = new LdapSearchConstraints();
constraints.SetControls(new LdapControl("1.2.840.113556.1.4.801", true, new byte[] { 48, 3, 2, 1, 7 }));
var getNtSecurityByteValue=attributeSet.GetAttribute("nTSecurityDescriptor").ByteValue;
var security = new CommonSecurityDescriptor(true, true, getNtSecurityByteValue, 0);
var self = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.SelfSid, null);
var userChangePassword = new Guid("AB721A53-1E2F-11D0-9819-00AA0040529B");
foreach (var ace in security.DiscretionaryAcl)
{
   if(ace.GetType().Name == "ObjectAce")
   {
      ObjectAce objAce = (ObjectAce)ace;
      if (objAce.AceType == AceType.AccessDeniedObject && objAce.SecurityIdentifier == self && objAce.ObjectAceType == userChangePassword)
      {
          cannotChangePassword = true;
          break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties#property-flag-descriptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `userAccountControl` value is a bit flag, meaning that every bit in the binary representation of the number is an "on" or "off" depending on if it's a 1 or 0. So the decimal value is meaningless.

You are already checking the value properly when you're checking if it's enabled:

```
isUserActive = !Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0002); //1. checks if user is enabled
```

Likewise, you should do the same when checking any of the other flags. The value of each is listed [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties#list-of-property-flags).

When you're checking if the password is set to never expire, you're comparing the decimal value, which won't always give you a correct answer. Instead, check the bit value:

```
passwordNeverExpires = Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x10000);
```

Similar for account is locked:

```
var accountLocked = Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0010);
```

For the user cannot change password setting, unfortunately that's more difficult and requires reading the permissions on the user account, which I have never done using the `Novell.Directory.Ldap` library. But I can try to point you in the right direction.

The account permissions are in the `nTSecurityDescriptor` attribute. Read this issue about how to get the byte array from that attribute: [How to read/set NT-Security-Descriptor attributes?](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/issues/89)

I wrote an article about how to get the byte array into a usable format: [Active Directory: Handling NT Security Descriptor attributes](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2019/07/25/nt-security-descriptors.html).

Then you'll be looking for two permissions that get added when the 'User cannot change password' checkbox is checked:

1. Deny Change Password to 'Everyone'
2. Deny Change Password to 'SELF'

You can probably get away with only looking for #2.

*Update:* I finally tried this out for myself. I had never used the `Novell.Directory.Ldap` library before, so this was new to me.

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40773088/1202807), I figured out that you need to set an LDAP control for it to return the `nTSecurityDescriptor` attribute at all:

```
var constraints = new LdapSearchConstraints();
constraints.SetControls(new LdapControl("1.2.840.113556.1.4.801", true
                                           , new byte[] {48, 3, 2, 1, 7}));
```

Once you retrieve the object, you can check the permissions like this:

```
var byteValue = attributeSet.GetAttribute("nTSecurityDescriptor").ByteValue;
var security = new CommonSecurityDescriptor(true, true, byteValue, 0);

var self = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.SelfSid, null);
var userChangePassword = new Guid("AB721A53-1E2F-11D0-9819-00AA0040529B");

var cannotChangePassword = false;

foreach (var ace in (security.DiscretionaryAcl)) {
    if (ace is ObjectAce objAce && objAce.AceType == AceType.AccessDeniedObject
            && objAce.SecurityIdentifier == self && objAce.ObjectAceType == userChangePassword) {
        cannotChangePassword = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

The GUID of the User-Change-Password permission is taken from the [Control Access Rights documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/1522b774-6464-41a3-87a5-1e5633c3fbbb).

Notice that you don't need to use `IADsSecurityDescriptor`, and thus you don't need a reference to `Interop.ActiveDs`. This is because we're given the value as a byte array already.

Comment: thank you for the reply. ```var userCannotChangePassword = Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0040);``` this always return false, though I have users with this option enabled.

Comment: @Varsh Apparently you're right, and I knew that, and I forgot. I just did a quick search and found an answer that I wrote about this back in 2018: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53959606/1202807

Comment: Hey, I already go through this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/adsi/reading-user-cannot-change-password-ldap-provider before but didn't get  actually how to implement it  here.

Comment: @Varsh I updated my answer with some resources that should point you in the right direction. It's not super easy, unfortunately.

Comment: thank you @Gabriel Luci, but I cannot find the `nTSecurityDescriptor` attribute in `LdapAttributeSet` . May be Novell.Directory.Ldap don't have this attribute.

Comment: @Varsh Is that the collection of returned attributes? It might be an attribute you have to specifically ask for. If you found the user by a search, you should be able to specify which attributes you want returned in that search.

Comment: update: I get the attribute `nTSecurityDescriptor` value. According to https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2019/07/25/nt-security-descriptors.html I used `Interop.ActiveDs` DLL and trying to get the attribute value `(IADsSecurityDescriptor)(attributeSet.GetAttribute("nTSecurityDescriptor").ByteValue)` it is giving error ```cannot convert type byte[] to IADsSecurityDescriptor``` .

Comment: I edited the question, Please check and guide.

Comment: @Varsh I updated my answer with the code on how to identify this. I learned some new things that I can use to update my article.

Comment: for the code ```foreach (ObjectAce ace in (security.DiscretionaryAcl))``` it is throwing the exception ```Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.AccessControl.CommonAce' to type 'System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectAce'.```

Comment: Another thing, can we have alternative to ```CommonSecurityDescriptor``` and ```SecurityIdentifier``` because they are showing warning that they are only supported on ```windows```

Comment: Hey @Gabriel Luci thank you so much for your time and effort. I updated the question with the answer worked for me. I will accept your answer. Just help me to make this code cross platform if you can.

Comment: @Varsh I updated the loop in my code with a better way of checking the type.

Comment: @Varsh Did you remove the reference to the "Active DS Type Library"?

Comment: Yes, I removed  "Active DS Type Library". Using just two namespaces for this code, ```System.Security.AccessControl``` and ```System.Security.Principal``` but both are supporting only windows.

Comment: @Varsh It appears so. I did some research today and I haven't been able to find an equivalent that is cross platform. I don't know if that has changed in .NET 6. You may only be able to run that part of your code from Windows. You could put an `if` statement around that part and only run it if it's running on Windows. Use [`OperatingSystem.IsWindows()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operatingsystem.iswindows?view=net-5.0) to check.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel Luci, but I need to deploy this code on linux environnment. So, checking the OS will not work for me.